# Clear a String with Java Pattern when it doesn't match

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an application where all input are validated by white list (*which is a regexp*). 
When the input doesn't match the regexp, the application throw an error message to the user and he should type another value.

Now, I have to be able to filter the input when he doesn't match the regexp. And I have no idea how to do this properly.

**This is what I want to do :**

```
String inputStr = ... //input value

Pattern p = getValidateurPattern();
if (!p.matcher(inputStr).matches()) {
    //a function which return a inputStr such as p.matcher(inputStr).matches() will be true
    inputStr = clearInputString(p, inputStr);
}
```

Unfortunately, the Pattern object is the only things I have to know the authorized values.

Is there a way do to this properly ?

Thanks

Comment: It depents how you input the value. Does the input happen by the console(Scanner for example) or by any GUI

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Consider that the input value is just a String which has to be cleaned. The inputStr comes from the client application and the function I'm talking about are on the server.

Comment: You can generate and try random strings until one is accepted by the pattern. Seriously, if there are no predefined restrictions on the pattern, there’s no reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this one .

```
Boolean b=Arrays.asList(arrayname).contains("String to compare");
```

Here Arrayname specifies the list of values in array which can be used to compare with our String.

it returns boolean value.
if the array contains searched String then it returns true else return false.
later you can use the true condition to do your required task.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Pattern object is the only things I have to know the authorized values

Comment: store the pattern in array and compare them